# Calculate weight distribution on 2D plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, torque, equilibrium, statics

I am trying to figure out how I can have a formula for the weight distribution on a square. But let me just describe what I am doing,
We have the classical horizontal beam support problem[image]

And I we can say that the weight on the support leg is inversly proportional to the distance of the load from the leg.

> w  ∝   1/d

and then removing the propotionalty it becomes,

> w  =  k ( 1/d )

after finding the costant `k`, the total weight can be written as

> k/d1 + k/d2 = total_weight

But does this formula also applies for the support legs placed in `2D plane` ? Like shown below:
[image]

Can I also say the weight distributed on three legs as ? :

> k/d1 + k/d2 + k/d3 = total_weight

Am I conceptually wrong? Can anyone show me the right direction to this problem?

**WHAT I KNOW:** I have alread gone through some readings and for the case of trianglular and rectangular planes there we have to consider the opposite area but I have to address this problem for a `n-sided` **polygon** hence trying to find a general formula for the weight distribution.

I have also asked this question before [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/781848/), I cannot formulate the solution in a Linear programming manner. Any suggestions on this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just do the usual analysis of having the net torque and force vanish on the polygon?

Comment: Like Sum of multiplication of individual force and distance equals to zero?